# TensorFlow Android Camera Demo

Tags: android, tensorflow

I have a questions about [TensorFlow Android Camera Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/), first of all, to start work with this demo I should download (clone) in my laptop all [Tenserflow depositary](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow)? Or it's possible to download just Android camera example (if yes, then how to do it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first download the source from our [repo](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources). Then follow the additional instructions for the [Android image demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/) to make it work.

Comment: Can I also ask you a question about phrase "The Android entries in <workspace_root>/WORKSPACE must be uncommented with the paths filled in appropriately depending on where you installed the NDK and SDK." . <workspace_root> -  it's a directory of the downloaded repo? What is WORKSPACE?

Comment: It should be a directory.

Comment: Found it, WORKSPACE is a file.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Yes, it's a file, and you should substitute directory paths in it. It's linked directly to from the instructions.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for just the camera demo, it looks like somebody did make a standalone version:
https://github.com/miyosuda/TensorFlowAndroidDemo

The main difference is that the official demo uses [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) (Google's build tool) to build and has shared dependencies with other tensorflow targets in the full repo, whereas this is uses the standard Android toolchain (including the native code).

If you want to use the official repo, it should be possible to use Android Studio from the demo app directory, as gradle calls out to Bazel in it's build targets.

Answer (score 4):

The [TensorFlow Android Camera Demo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/) is now build every night in Jenkins:
http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-android/

The "Last Successful Artifacts" section has a "+" sign that you can expand a couple of times to find the `tensorflow_demo.apk`, which you can then install.

[image: jenkins_screenshot]

Follow [the installation instructions in the README file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/README.md#install) to install the APK.

Comment: Yeah, I also saw it!